# CSS for Canvas element (SoundCloud duration)?

Tags: jquery, css, soundcloud, tampermonkey

I'm trying to style the duration of SoundCloud players (Stylish or Tampermonkey).

[image]

I dunno canvas enough. How can I style the duration in color and size?

It is the last canvas in `.waveform__layer`

```
<div class="waveform__layer waveform__scene">
    <canvas aria-hidden="true" class="g-box-full sceneLayer" width="900" height="110"></canvas>
    <canvas aria-hidden="true" class="g-box-full sceneLayer waveformCommentsNode loaded" width="900" height="110"></canvas>
    <canvas aria-hidden="true" class="g-box-full sceneLayer" width="900" height="110"></canvas>
</div>
```

Example page: https://soundcloud.com/kenny-dope/fmg-1-side-b-set-if-off-7-instrumental-strafe

Answer (score 1):

You can't, the canvas part is styled with JavaScript, so not possible with Stylish.